# How to stack Fullcalendar header on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar.io and my layout looks like this on desktop-PCs:

```
June 2016                           [<][Today][>]
             My calendar is here
```

However on mobile, it looks like this:

```
          June 2016                           
                      [<][Today][>]
             My calendar is here
```

or that:

```
            June 20[<][Today][>]
             My calendar is here
```

Basically what I want is that all elements from the header stack centered on mobile. Is that possible?

Comment: the calendar uses a grid system which is unsuited to mobile / reponsive layouts, unfortunately. There just isn't enough width. I suggest on mobile devices you use one of the available "list" style views, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just add this to your CSS. You may need to adjust your break point or add it to your existing break point.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .fc-toolbar > div {
        float: left !important;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Mobile will look like this:

```
[Normally Left]
[Normally Center]
[Normally Right]
--------- Your Calendar ------------
```

**Optional:**

You can loose the !important, if you are more specific in your selector. Example:

```
.calendar .fc-toolbar > div.fc-left, 
.calendar .fc-toolbar > div.fc-center, 
.calendar .fc-toolbar > div.fc-right {
    float: left !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```